# Increasing, decreasing, none or all?

Tags: code-golf, number, parsing

Take two inputs, a non-empty vector/list containing digits `1` and `2` and a string (no, you may not take `0/1` instead). The string will be one of the following (in lowercase, exactly as written below:

```
increasing
decreasing
ones
twos
all
none
```

If the string is ____ then you shall return the indices ___:

- `increasing` ... where the list changes from `1` to `2` (every `2` that follows directly after a `1`)
- `decreasing` ... where the list changes from `2` to `1` (every `1` that follows directly after a `2`)
- `ones` ... of all digits that are `1`
- `twos` ... of all digits that are `2`
- `all` ... all the digits
- `none` ... none of the digits. `0` is fine if the list is 1-indexed. A negative number is fine if the list is 0-indexed. You may also output an empty list or string.

#### Test cases:

These are 1-indexed. You may choose if you want 1-indexed or 0-indexed. The same vectors are used for different strings in the test cases.

```
--------------------------------
Vector:
1 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2

String       - Output
increasing   - 3, 7, 11
decreasing   - 6, 9
ones         - 1, 2, 6, 9, 10 
twos         - 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 11
all          - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
none         - 0 / []

------------------------------------
Vector:
1

String:
ones         - 1
all          - 1
decreasing / increasing / twos / none  - 0 / []
```

## Scoring

As this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the answer with the least bytes wins.

#### Explanations are encouraged!

Comment: So far none of the answers seem to output a list as shown in the example. (ie, joined by ", " with no trailing delimiter).  As the challenge text doesn't say how flexible the list can be, what's normally accepted for challenges like this?

Comment: It's normally very flexible. As long as it's a list of numbers you're fine.

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (Firefox 30-57), <s>74</s> 73 bytes

```
(a,[s],i=0,p)=>[for(e of a)if({i:e>p,d:e<p,o:e<2,t:e>1,a:1}[p=e,i++,s])i]
```

Array comprehensions are a neat way of combining `map` and `filter` in one go. Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @edc65.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>136</s> <s>131</s> <s>119</s> <s>108</s> 97 bytes

- Saved five bytes; using a `lambda` function.
- Saved twelve bytes thanks to [TFeld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38592/tfeld); golfing two conditions.
- Saved eleven bytes thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder); using `enumerate()` instead of `range(len())`.
- Saved eleven bytes by using a list instead of a dictionary and using `0`-indexing (as in [TFeld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/144031/increasing-decreasing-none-or-all/144035#144035)) and golfing `"adinot".find(m[0])` to `ord(m[0])/3-32`.

```python
lambda l,m:[j for j,k in enumerate(l)if[1,j*k<j*l[~-j],0,j*k>j*l[~-j],0,k<2,k>1][ord(m[0])/3-32]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY7NDoIwEITvPsWGE5ASodwM8iK1hypF@09KjfHiq1cwknCFyRxmDt/ODu/wcBbH/nyJmplrx0AjcyISeudBIgXCArdPwz0LPNWZ6EmFZK4amWvyKSRF5VzbVVUNRqqtKHG@Sw0paXasixpTGgcvbIA@nU7AZLy4WoU5UwSJsDfP2SjsPckOW8CO7wSd5WMCP20Dw8vtA5nWf24jaKdfl8X4BQ)

Comment: Since the input is always `1`or `2`, you can change `(l[j]>1)*(l[~-j]<2)` to `(l[j]>l[~-j])`  for [119 bytes](http://goo.gl/oezo3S)

Comment: Also, you can [save a byte](https://goo.gl/gmBPf7) by switching to 0-indexed

Comment: @TFeld Thanks; though I think I will stick with `1`-indexed.

Comment: [108 bytes](https://tio.run/##nY7BDoIwEETvfkWzJ8BqLMdG@RHkUKVgS7slUGOM0V@vSCR6hckkM5nkZbe9@4vDNFSHYzDCnkpBDLU812tWuY5o2hCFROLVyk54GZlYVQ9QwHXSZDox@WujCwrlOOx/gwPe7FMKfsiMURDA2XNbSx/ZfFfERWg7hZ5UUc4oGZxOZn/l0wtKQOG5k6JXWEO8mgOWciHoUPZARs0D/c0tA4UxX24miMOv08XwBg), using `enumerate()`

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>117</s> <s>111</s> <s>110</s> <s>99</s> <s>97</s> 92 bytes

```python
lambda l,t:[i for i,v in enumerate(l)if[l[i+i/~i]<v,0,v<2,v>1,1,l[i+i/~i]>v][ord(t[0])/3%7]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lc1NCsIwEAXgvafIRtrgQH9cCNL2IjGLaBMdSCcljRE3Xj1WEbdWBt6Dxwcz3sPFUZ1Me0hWDcdeMQthL5AZ5xlCZEhM03XQXgWdW45GWIEbLB4omwglxKaG2FVQwXfvohTO93kQpeTFdr2TMo0eKTCTi5es31d9cm4JGdLJazUhnTO@@ql7/Y92pKclLtzcIqesXcJo/pvx9AQ)

`0`-indexed

Switched to using [Jonathan's indexing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144034/38592), and golfed `ord(m[0])/3-32` to `ord(t[0])/3%7`

Comment: You can golf `l[i]==2` to `l[i]>1`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>112</s> <s>83</s> 81 bytes

```hs
s%l=[i|(i,p,q)<-zip3[1..]l$l!!0:l,elem(s!!0,1<2)$zip"idota"[q<p,p<q,p<2,1<p,1<2]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYvRCoMwDEXf/YpaFFqosrq3oZ@wLyh9KLNsYbFWKwzG/r2LY4wRcu9NTnJz6e4Rc041DgZeAlRUi@ybJ8Sj0W1rscKyPJxQefSTSJSV7jtZ0QGHcd4cN0sfVewX6o5Y3Lm1uWkYQtrYwIy2xS8qrbpP6a@S22JyEAhPLp6ZiCuEjbVM1PuXlMxwCJfVuwThyhUf/d8wB5/Itse8m0MkDbTkNr8B) Example usage: `"increasing"%[1,1,2,1,2]`. Results are 1-indexed.

Partly inspired by [Lynn's Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144096/56433).

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>32</s> <s>31</s> <s>30</s> 29  bytes

```
dQ~fQGqfOOGofGd1=fQGfO[]Xhjs)
```

Output is 1-based, or empty.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PyWwLi3QvTDN3989P809xdAWyEvzj46NyMgq1vz/P9pQwVDBCAwNoSSQjuXKzEsuSk0szsxLBwA)

#### Explanation

The code computes the six possible outputs for the array input, and then selects the appropriate output depending on the string input.

To select the output, the ASCII code points of all characters of the string input are added. The result modulo 9 gives `6`, `1`, `5`, `2`, `7`, `0` respectively for `'increasing'`, `'decreasing'`, `'ones'`, `'twos'`, `'all'`, `'none'`. Since all the resulting numbers are distinct this can be used as a selection criterion.

Instead of actually performing a modulo 9 operation on the sum, the list of possible inputs is extended to 9 entries (some of which are dummy), and so indexing into that list is automatically done modulo 9.

```
d     % Implicit input: numeric vector. Push vector of consecutive differences.
      % Contains -1, 0 or 1
Q~    % For each entry: add 1, negate. This turns -1 into 1, other values into 0
f     % Push indices of nonzeros
Q     % Add 1 to each entry (compensates the fact that computing consecutive
      % differences removes one entry). This the output for 'decreasing'
Gq    % Push input again. Subtract 1 from the code points
f     % Push indices of nonzeros. This is the output for 'twos'
OO    % Push two zeros. These are used as placeholders
Go    % Push input and compute parity of each entry
f     % Push indices of nonzeros. This is the output for 'ones'
Gd    % Push input and compute consecutive differences
1=    % Test each entry for equality with 1
f     % Push indices of nonzeros 
Q     % Add 1. This is the output for 'increasing'
Gf    % Push indices for all input (nonzero) entries. This is the output for 'all'
O     % Push zeros. Used as placeholder
[]    % Push empty array. This is the output for 'none'
Xh    % Concatenate stack into a cell array
j     % Input a string
s     % Sum of code points
)     % Use as an index into the cell aray. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>266</s> <s>217</s> <s>213</s> <s>205</s> <s>172</s> <s>171</s> <s>155</s> 131 bytes

```java
s->a->{int i=0,l=0,c=s.charAt(0)-97;for(int e:a){if(++i>1&(c==8&e>l|c==3&e<l)|c==14&(l=e)<2|c>18&l>1|c<1)System.out.print(i+",");}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVDRasIwFH3vV4Q@lGS2wbrB3NoGZLAf8FF8yGJ00TQJSapI7bd36eZE9jro5QYO517uOSd7eqSZNlztN4de1EZbD/aBw17UHD8U0T3XeCHxtlHMC62GYcQkdQ4sQBuBUM5TLxh4v26US2@F2qXgTSvX1NyWQvnVmhBwABXoXUZoRtrAAVFNUxkeqxxmn9QuPJyi7OW52GoLhwX@SlErtnAyESRPIKuqecKJvATwmPBSogHlTwmUFUfl7MJIPk8kyS@szNHy7DyvsW48NsGQh2ISpzEquq4PEQbjpvmQwfjV/1GLDaipUPAnwGoNqN05dE051AFTY@QZxkIxy6kLWzHClDFuPFT8BL6TtnkKQs9@O78DA@5Qcbv416RU8G5609vwcfW04m4cJX/SIylRKccRUuH3/qHURV3/BQ)

Comment: If you define `y` as a `char`, you can golf equality tests like `y.equals("a")` to `y=='a'`, `y==97` or even `y<98`.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Was just changing it :)

Comment: The TIO at least is not the output I would expect.  While only given by example, the list requires a space between elements and no trailing comma.

Comment: Since `19` is `c`'s highest value, `c==19` is equal to `c>18`.

Comment: 15 bytes can be saved but using indexing from 1: `for(;i<a.length;i++){if(i>0&(c==8&a[i]>l|c==3&a[i]<l))f=1;l=a[i];` can be replaced with `for(int e:a){if(++i>1&(c==8&e>l|c==3&e<l))f=1;l=e;`

Comment: 131 bytes: `s->a->{int i=0,l=0,c=s.charAt(0)-97;for(int e:a){if(++i>1&(c==8&e>l|c==3&e<l)|c==14&(l=e)<2|c>18&l>1|c<1)System.out.print(i+",");}}`

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 27 bytes

```
>2\0;
NÇ
Ị
=2

ḟ
⁹Ḣ“hɠ»iµĿT
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/OKMbAmsvvcDvXw91dXLZGXFwPd8znetS48@GORY8a5mScXHBod@ahrUf2h/z//z/aUEcBiIxgyBCJAWLH/lfKy89LVQIA)

-3 thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan).

Comment: [Save three bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/v8EQuT0NbA2uuh7u7uGyNuLge7pjP9ahx58Mdix41zMk4ueDQ7sxDW4/sD/n//3@0oY4CEBnBkCESA8SO/a@UkppclJpYnJmXrgQA) by using the dictionary word "diota" - note that link 0 gets it right, but you could reorder again and use "antidote" or other such word and allow your test harness to work again.

Comment: @JonathanAllan I thought link `0` was the bottom-most link, but apparently it's like `Ç` but weirder, thanks! (also I just learned a new word :p)

Answer (score 1):

## J, 73 bytes

```
g=.[:I.[=0,2-/\]
(_1 g])`(1 g])`(1=])`(2=])`(i.@#@])`_1:@.('idotan'i.{.@[)
```

Would be curious to see how this can be significantly condensed -- I believe it can (10 chars just for all those agenda parens!)

- `g` - helper verb for increasing and decreasing, which just amount to comparing the values of infix `\` runs of size 2
- The rest just grabs the first character from the "command" and executes the corresponding case using Agenda `@.`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P91WL9rKUy/a1kDHSFc/JpYrzVZPI95QIT1WM0EDRtmCSCMwmannoOwAZMQbWjnoaahnpuSXJOapZ@pV6zlEa3JxpSZn5CuoZ@YlqyukKRgCoREYGkJJEO3npAckzRQMDaCqU1IJqDZVsIAqzc9LLcapFqqmpDyfoJrEnBxCSvKAduFU8/8/AA)

Comment: Do `1=]` and `2=]` not work? Also, what if `g` took a number as its left argument and a list as its right argument and returned the indices where `2-/\ ` applied to the list equaled the left argument. That way you could pass it `_1` or `1` to find decreasing and increasing instead of using an adverb.

Comment: @cole Good comments.  I made the changes, and the result is much cleaner, though 73 still seems like a high byte count.  I mean, J is tying the JS here.... the shame!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 92 bytes

```python
lambda a,s:[i for i,(x,y)in enumerate(zip([0]+a,a))if[0<x<y,0,y<2,y>1,1,x>y][ord(s[0])/3%7]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5BbsIwEEX3OcVsothiROOwQEKBi7heuMQpIyV25HFpzOWDWRRV@ov3pbd4S0634LttPH9uk52/BgsW@aQJxhCBUKyYJXlw/md20SYnHrQI3ZqdRSsljbrt1z5ji7nvMF8UKlwv2egQB8HFkx@H@mjMdoczaIVQ1v1N/YMXm4q5aA35a3SWyX/D4N4YvGNIv4HBThP4cps9LxMlIatXLEPpZD7BEsknaGrVclMzwijuCCyr7Qk)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 91 bytes

```hs
(c:_)!l=[i|(i,y,x)<-zip3[1..]l$l!!0:l,c/='i'||x<y,c>'d'||x>y,c/='o'||y<2,c<'t'||y>1,c/='n']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYvRCoMgFIbv9xQmAwtcm@0urDfYE4QMMdlkJ4sMlqN3dxq7GAf@7z/f4Tyle2mAEHJV34sMms5suaGergU/fcx07VhZCjhCll1qoOrcEEO2beWeqpb0qbZ@12PsnldUcbKk2rJdWyICoAZ1jDJa7cN@GSkOzqUjNlbNWjpjH5jiXv8to9UuYnmPCRIgpo0Si8MgjY3fg5xuKJ9mYxdUojyDokDOhS8)

Laikoni saved a byte.

Comment: You can save a byte with `(i,y,x)<-zip3[1..]l$l!!0:l`.

Comment: [Some competition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144093/56433)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 27 bytes

```
`fN!+mmëI=2ε¬moΘẊe><€¨Ÿȧö¨←
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/PyHNT1E7N/fwak9bo3NbD63JzT834@GurlQ7m0dNaw6tOLrjxPLD2w6teNQ24f///0qJOTlK/6MNdQx1jMDQEEoC6VgA)

-9 thanks to [H.PWiz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71256/h-pwiz).

I'm quite proud of this answer.

Comment: [Golfed](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/PyHNT1E7N//cjIe7ulLtbHJzD68@t9XWyPPQmkdNaw6teNTUdnT3@eZH0zYB2W0T/v//r5SZl1yUmlicmZeu9D/aUMdQxwgMDaEkkI4FAA) mostly by using `ΘẊ>` and `ΘẊ<` and `\`fN`

Comment: @H.PWiz how didn't I see those honestly

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/PyHNT1E7N/fwak9bo3NbD63JzT834@GurlQ7m0dNaw6tOLrjxPLD2w6teNQ24f///0opqclFqYnFmXnpSv@jDXUMdYzA0BBKAulYAA) A list indexed at `0` is the last element.

Comment: @H.PWiz Ooh I thought that the compressed string would be `¨₆Żσa¨` instead that's why I didn't use that feature, thanks. And now I can say it *ties Jelly*.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 131 bytes

Based on [xcali](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72767/xcali)'s approach since string matching is shorter then my array version.

```
def D(s):[.[1]|gsub(" ";"")|match(s;"g").offset+(s|length)];./"
"|{i:D("12"),d:D("21"),o:D("1"),t:D("12"),a:D("."),n:[]}[.[0][0:1]]
```

Assumes jq is invoked with `-Rs` options and input appears on two lines e.g.

```
decreasing
1 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2
```

Expanded:

```
def D(s): [
      .[1]                              # find where s appears
    | gsub(" ";"")                      # in the input and add
    | match(s;"g").offset + (s|length)  # length to get ending index
  ]
;

  ./"\n"                                # split on newline
| {i:D("12"),                           # increasing
   d:D("21"),                           # decreasing
   o:D("1"),                            # ones
   t:D("2"),                            # twos
   a:D("."),                            # all
   n:[]                                 # none
  }[.[0][0:1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY9NDoIwEIX3nKIZN20UpCzbLRvOgF0glB@DLdI2LsSrW0tjzCRvvjfzksncHv6AJrU4m3SyRxWDTrarbMykhouiiKIiFv1p6MD9Hi2xIazOaiq2wbgrBgQcgGz3xrYjNhwGIJnueyPtEZttlmqwIxG8OkMC22tiJQZaADl1OxU0kI6zAPa/bHbKAihWi3c4l4s6Z1QI7z96sZNWxqepcvOcxi@CWZtnqp2Npv0C)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>233</s> <s>229</s> 216 bytes

```java
l->s->{int i=s.charAt(0)-97,k=0,j=1;for(s=(l+"").replaceAll("[^12]","");s.length()*j>0;System.out.print(j++<0?"":(k+=j)+","),s=s.substring(j))j=i<1?0:s.indexOf(i<4?"21":i<9?"12":i<14?" ":i<15?"1":"2")+(i>2&i<9?1:0);}
```

This String approach ended up longer than I was expecting.. But even thought I'm hugely out-golfed by [the other Java 8 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144047/52210), I decided to post it anyway.
It can definitely be golfed, even with this approach.. The "none" and "increase/decreasing" mainly caused some workaround that cost some bytes..

The result is 1-indexed.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##3VNba9swFH73rzjoYUi1IyyzUupbCIXBYGMPfSwtqLKSylFkY8npgslvz2Qn624Je95sLB2f852LPp1T8y2fNa00dbU@qE3bdA5qr6O9U5peZcEfumVvhFONGY1Cc2vhM1dmCACs404J@HAC5J@UdRHcNcb2G9nl965TZlWWIKA46FlpZ@WgjANVWCpeeLdwOCaz25toXcRRXbBs2XTYFliHCBHayVZzIRdaY/TwxJJHFHl1ZqmWZuVeMLmqyzi731knN7TpHW19NofrMMzjOUIpXodFTULvRSLrM9r@2U4F4ZqQulA5m8eppcpU8uuXJVb5@zlKGEpVfjtHLBkF5lUwCddehVKUIBJiVSbvRhBLY5LtD1ngmWj7Z@2ZOBGybVQFG08SPlLw8AicDOCfYFxGmvKPxsmV7Epw0ro7biUUYOQrLLqO7yZEiSfZUm7Hf8wiFiXTy06r3wnJpphjFPw9VARIGdFJbn1ydAFRyb8hGiPtJZt7bS7auNaXTMbH/Nl27uCYDAOvKsw8u/v/7nT@Wv/VK9sHUwP7OdtyJ39p9snpfF9HcBwCcLtWkmHK8fvUavOWEUJAkPkvPDocixKUt63evaEI5ULI1hf6A3Mm6Kns/eEb)

```java
l->s->{                          // Method with List and String parameters
  int i=s.charAt(0)-97,          //  First character of the String - 97
                                 //   (i=8; d=3; o=14; t=19; a=0; n=13)
      k=0,                       //  Total counter
      j=1;                       //  Index integer
  for(s=(l+"")                   //  toString of the List,
         .replaceAll("[^12]","");//   and leave only the 1s and 2s 
      s.length()*j>0             //  Loop as long as `j` and the size of the String
                                 //  are both larger than 0
      ;                          //   After every iteration:
      System.out.print(          //    Print:
       j++<0?                    //     If `j` is -1:
        ""                       //      Print nothing
       :                         //     Else:
        (k+=j)+",")              //      Print the current index
      ,s=s.substring(j))         //    And then remove the part of the String we've checked
    j=i<1?                       //   If "all":
                                 //    Change `j` to 0
      :                          //   Else:
       s.indexOf(                //    Replace `j` with the next index of:
        i<1?                     //     If "all":
         s.charAt(0)+""          //      The next character
        :i<4?                    //     Else-if "decreasing":
         "21"                    //      Literal "21"
        :i<9?                    //     Else-if "increasing":
         "12"                    //      Literal "12"
        :i<14?                   //     Else-if "none":
         " "                     //      Literal space (any char that isn't present)
        :i<15?                   //     Else-if "one":
         "1"                     //      Literal "1"
        :                        //     Else(-if "two"):
         "2")                    //      Literal "2"
       +(i>2&i<9?1:0);           //     +1 if it's "increasing"/"decreasing"
                                 //  End of loop (implicit / single-line body)
}                                // End of method
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 71 + 2 (`-nl`) = 73 bytes

```perl
$p=/l/?'.':/t/?2:/^o/?1:/d/?21:/i/?12:0;$_=<>;s/ //g;say pos while/$p/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYdBCsMgFAX3PYULIavk@YVstIknyBVaCg2pIPlShdDL90dKGZhh8vpOo4jOExJCN3QOFcE63BiBHJ5tWmIb64zX9@k6@wIFbL48PipzUccrphU6YxOpB5cLKVL2B/3d@uVcI@9F@mUcDBnp93QC)

Revised logic is effectively the same as the below explanation, but the pattern matches have been shortened.

*Previously:*

```perl
$p=/all/?'.':/^o/?1:/^t/?2:/^d/?21:/^i/?12:0;$_=<>;s/ //g;say pos while/$p/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LchBCoMwFATQfU/xFwFXOknAjanmBF6hRajYwMeEJiC9fL9pKQPzmEnri3sRlUYszPBN1wy4RXhTKfC28qh8Z6ivHbRT9/E6uQwCNpeXN6WY6XgGXqESNpFyxHwxZMj@Yv5d/cRUQtyztHPfaaOl3fkE)

Outputs nothing if the criteria is not matched.

**Explained:**

```perl
$p=          # set the pattern to seach based on the input string
  /all/?'.'  # any character
 :/^o/?1     # starts with 'o', find ones
 :/^t/?2     # starts with 't', find twos
 :/^d/?21    # starts with 'd', find decreasing
 :/^i/?12    # starts with 'i', find increasing
 :0;         # anything else: create pattern that won't match
$_=<>;s/ //g;# read the digits and remove spaces
say pos while/$p/g # output position(s) of all matches
```